# Silverlight 5 : How to stop a Combobox from using implicit data template

Tags: templates, combobox, silverlight-5.0, implicit

Love the new Implicit Data Templates, but I've just run into a problem with them.

My ComboBox is picking a DataTemplate which matches the ItemsSources type instead of following my DisplayMemberPath settings.  Is there a way to tell the control to not look for DataTemplates?

```
     <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="DTO.Name" SelectedValue="{Binding DefaultModifierGroup, Mode=TwoWay}" 
ItemsSource="{Binding MenuRepository.ModifierGroups, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't use DisplayMemberPath anymore. You probably need to created new data template inside that combobox.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication1"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="local:Person">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <StackPanel>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SilverlightApplication1 {
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl {
        public MainPage() {
            this.DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();

            Items = new List<Person>{
                new Person() { Name ="Name1", Address ="Address1" },
                new Person() { Name ="Name2", Address ="Address2" },
                new Person() { Name ="Name3", Address ="Address3" }
            };

        }

        public IList<Person> Items { get; set; }

    }

    public class Person {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't remember where the code is that I needed this solved, but I am pretty sure this is what I ended up doing.  Thanks for posting the answer though, hopefully its helpful to others as well!